# Please help I keep getting back a TypeError $(...)is null

Tags: javascript

My teacher made a js file and told us to find the errors and fix them. But, I'm stuck on this.

```
//this function is called when the user enters invalid data into the form and hits the calculate button

function clearField(field_name) {

//set the value of the passed in field name to blank

$("field_name").value = "";

$("field_name").value = "";   keeps returning an error message like this:
```

> TypeError $(...) is null

Comment: Are you sure you're supposed to get the object via `$("field_name")` and not `$(field_name)`? + Are you sure you have jQuery/whatever included?

Comment: First of all tell us what you're getting in `field_name`

Comment: `.value`?  not `.val()`?

Comment: @sideroxylon `jQuery` or not `jQuery`? Unfortunately the OP hasn't provided us with enough information to safely assume this...

Comment: It isn't jQuery. jQuery wouldn't return `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I did it in quotation marks on accident.
I redid it as `$(field_name).value == ("");` and it worked.

Answer (score -2):

Since `field_name` is a parameter of your function, it should not be enclosed in quotation marks.

It should be:

`$(field_name).value() = ";` only

**EDIT**

My bad. It should be `$(field_name).val("");` rather

Comment: @Justcode I just based my answer to the available resources that the OP gave.

Comment: I think `.val()` pushes this answer a little further than we can safely step at this point. We don't know what JS libs the OP is using or even if the teacher rolled their own with the jQuery like syntax. The _EDIT_ almost renders this answer invalid...